# MySQL offset weirdness

Tags: mysql

I have problem with a MySQL query with an OFFSET and LIMIT clause.

It *seems* to be returning a **different** list of records based on the **number of columns** selected.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known "*feature*" or something I misunderstood somewhere?

If I select 1 column, the offset works normally.  If I add a second column it seems to internally reset the offset to 0.

Here are my two seemingly similar queries.  Please notice the result in the **id** column:

The two queries run back to back are as follows (note it doesn't matter if you add 1 extra or multiple extra columns to the query):

```
mysql> SELECT t0.id, t0.max_retries FROM dtc_queue_job t0 WHERE t0.status = 'running' LIMIT 12 OFFSET 100;
+-----+-------------+
| id  | max_retries |
+-----+-------------+
| 123 |        NULL |
| 124 |        NULL |
| 125 |        NULL |
| 126 |        NULL |
| 127 |        NULL |
| 128 |        NULL |
| 129 |        NULL |
| 130 |        NULL |
| 131 |        NULL |
| 132 |        NULL |
| 133 |        NULL |
| 134 |        NULL |
+-----+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t0.id FROM dtc_queue_job t0 WHERE t0.status = 'running' LIMIT 12 OFFSET 100;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 108 |
| 109 |
| 110 |
| 111 |
| 112 |
| 113 |
| 114 |
| 115 |
| 116 |
| 117 |
| 118 |
| 119 |
+-----+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Background:

1) Table has 112 records.

2) Create Table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `dtc_queue_job` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `worker_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `method` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `args` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crc_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `when_us` decimal(18,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expires_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `started_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `finished_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `elapsed` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `max_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `run_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stalls` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `max_stalls` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exceptions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `max_exceptions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `failures` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `max_failures` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retries` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `max_retries` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `job_crc_hash_idx` (`crc_hash`,`status`),
  KEY `job_priority_idx` (`priority`,`when_us`),
  KEY `job_when_idx` (`when_us`),
  KEY `job_status_idx` (`status`,`when_us`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=145 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

3) IDs of the records:

```
mysql> SELECT t0.id as id_1 FROM dtc_queue_job t0;
+------+
| id_1 |
+------+
|  123 |
|  124 |
|  125 |
|  126 |
|  127 |
|  128 |
|  129 |
|  130 |
|  131 |
|  132 |
|  133 |
|  134 |
|   20 |
|   21 |
|   22 |
|   23 |
|   24 |
|   25 |
|   26 |
|   27 |
|   28 |
|   29 |
|   30 |
|   31 |
|   32 |
|   33 |
|   34 |
|   35 |
|   36 |
|   37 |
|   38 |
|   39 |
|   40 |
|   41 |
|   42 |
|   43 |
|   44 |
|   45 |
|   46 |
|   47 |
|   48 |
|   49 |
|   50 |
|   51 |
|   52 |
|   53 |
|   54 |
|   55 |
|   56 |
|   57 |
|   58 |
|   59 |
|   60 |
|   61 |
|   62 |
|   63 |
|   64 |
|   65 |
|   66 |
|   67 |
|   68 |
|   69 |
|   70 |
|   71 |
|   72 |
|   73 |
|   74 |
|   75 |
|   76 |
|   77 |
|   78 |
|   79 |
|   80 |
|   81 |
|   82 |
|   83 |
|   84 |
|   85 |
|   86 |
|   87 |
|   88 |
|   89 |
|   90 |
|   91 |
|   92 |
|   93 |
|   94 |
|   95 |
|   96 |
|   97 |
|   98 |
|   99 |
|  100 |
|  101 |
|  102 |
|  103 |
|  104 |
|  105 |
|  106 |
|  107 |
|  108 |
|  109 |
|  110 |
|  111 |
|  112 |
|  113 |
|  114 |
|  115 |
|  116 |
|  117 |
|  118 |
|  119 |
+------+
112 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

4) Other info:

MySQL loaded from the official docker image:

```
root@baf5881b2eb2:/# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
root@baf5881b2eb2:/# mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.7.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make good sense to use `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` without specifying an *ordering* for your result set.  This is typically done via an `ORDER BY` clause.  The basic idea here is that you need to tell MySQL to take the first 12 records with respect to the ordering of some column.

Note that there is no internal order to a MySQL table, so if you don't specify an ordering, then there is no guarantee that the order of records you get back would be the same with each query.  It might be, but then again it might not be.

If you run the following query multiple times, I expect you will get the same result set, so long as the underlying data does not change in between queries:

```
SELECT
    id,
    max_retries
FROM dtc_queue_job
WHERE
    status = 'running'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 100;
```

Here we are taking the first 12 records, offset by 100, with regard to the `id` column.

Comment: Interesting, you're correct, that does appear to yield consistent results.

Comment: @mmucklo Moving forward, you should probably always use `ORDER BY` if you use `LIMIT`, unless you really don't care what you get back.